# TypeError: unsupported operand typ

Tags: python, python-3.x

i m just new to python and is trying to learn this language. i tried running a code in python but got an error can anyone help me
here is my code:

```
def cel_to_fahr(c):
    f = c * 9/5 + 32
    return f

c = input("enter the temperature in celcius:")
print(cel_to_fahr(c))
```

the error i m getting is:

```
File ".\prg.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(cel_to_fahr(c))
  File ".\prg.py", line 2, in cel_to_fahr
    f = c * 9/5 + 32
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int
```

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `input()` returns the string value. So convert it to either `int` or `float`

```
c = int(input("enter the temperature in celcius:"))
```

OR

```
c = float(input("enter the temperature in celcius:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert your input to number. `input()` function returns string value

```
c = input("enter the temperature in celcius:")
print(cel_to_fahr(int(c)))
```